# Passing ObservableList from one class to another

Tags: java, javafx

Hi there I am trying to pass an ObservableList from one class to another but seem to be getting an error

> java.lang.NullPointerException

```html
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at animal_sanctuary.maintenanceController.populateBreedTable(maintenanceController.java:99)
 at animal_sanctuary.maintenanceController.initialize(maintenanceController.java:44)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
 at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
 at animal_sanctuary.Controller.loadScreen(Controller.java:133)
 at animal_sanctuary.Main.start(Main.java:33)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
 at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can you tell me what i am doing wrong its is driving me crazy .

Here is my Code

**Class 1**

```html
//===================================================
    //      ***** GET INFO FROM DB *****
    //===================================================
    
    public ObservableList<Breed> getBreed(){

        Statement stmt = null;

        ArrayList<Breed> bre = new ArrayList<Breed>();
        try {
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM breeds;");
            while(rs.next()){
                String s = rs.getString("breed");
                System.out.println(s);
                Breed b = new Breed(s);
                bre.add(b);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ObservableList<Breed> myObservableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(bre);;

        return myObservableList;
    }
```

**Class 2**

```html
public void populateBreedTable(){

        ObservableList<Breed> b = myController.getBreed();
        //breedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("breed"));
        //itemTable.setItems();

    }
```

Thanks you for your time :)

**UPDATE

> public class maintenanceController implements Initializable, ControlledScreen {

```
Controller myController;
Connection conn;

@FXML
RadioButton rbType ,rbBreed, rbLocation;
@FXML
TextField addItemTb;
@FXML
TableView<Breed>  itemTable;
@FXML
TableColumn<Breed, String > breedCol;
@FXML
TableView<Type>  itemTable1;
@FXML
TableColumn<Type, String > TypeCol;


/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    try {
        conn = myController.getConnection();
        populateBreedTable();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void setScreenParent(Controller screenParent) {
    myController = screenParent;
}

@FXML
private void goToMainScreen(ActionEvent event) {
    myController.setScreen(Main.mainScreen1ID);
}
```

**

> public boolean setScreen(final String name) {
>           if (screens.get(name) != null) {   //screen loaded
>               final DoubleProperty opacity = opacityProperty();

```
        if (!getChildren().isEmpty()) {    //if there is more than one screen
            Timeline fade = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)),
                    new KeyFrame(new Duration(1000), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                            getChildren().remove(0);                    //remove the displayed screen
                            getChildren().add(0, screens.get(name));     //add the screen
                            Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline(
                                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)),
                                    new KeyFrame(new Duration(800), new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)));
                            fadeIn.play();
                        }
                    }, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)));
            fade.play();

        } else {
            setOpacity(0.0);
            getChildren().add(screens.get(name));       //no one else been displayed, then just show
            Timeline fadeIn = new Timeline(
                    new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(opacity, 0.0)),
                    new KeyFrame(new Duration(2500), new KeyValue(opacity, 1.0)));
            fadeIn.play();
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("screen hasn't been loaded!!! \n");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: @JornVernee I have done an update thanks.

Comment: It seems to my like you never instantiated ```myController```

Comment: And by the way, those snippet things don't work with java. You should just use regular code blocks.

Comment: @JornVernee I have been using the controller in other method tho

Comment: It looks like `myController` is null. Note that in the default use of JavaFX, the controller is instantiated from the `FXMLLoader` and you retrieve it from the loader (so you should not instantiate it yourself, as per the other comments).

Comment: Be careful you don't close your connection and your statement which can cause a connection leak

Comment: @James_D it is a controler parent to my fmxl contoller to pass data between  controller when i change screens

Comment: Well, assuming that line is the line throwing the exception (which is the only possibility in the code you have shown), `myController` is null. Show where you initialize it.

Comment: @James_D I have done an update

Comment: OK. There is nowhere in that code where you initialize `myController`.

Comment: @James_D yes there is public void setScreenParent(Controller screenParent) {
    myController = screenParent;
}

Comment: @James_D this works fine for all my other classes . This how it is done following the oracle tutorials

Comment: Ah, OK, didn't see that. But where is it called from? You should create (probably from scratch, given the complexity of this application) a [MCVE] and post it in the question. It's pretty much impossible to diagnose the problem without enough code to reproduce it.

Comment: @James_D Ya okay your probably write I got it working by calling the sql in class itself but i was not what I was planing. But anyway think for your help sir. Much appreciated

Comment: Oh, actually... I see the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem arises from the order in which the methods are executed. `initialize()` is called by the `FXMLLoader` as part of the process of loading the fxml file. Since your `initialize()` method invokes `populateBreedTable()`, the `populateBreedTable()` method is invoked before the call to `FXMLLoader.load()` completes.

The `myController` variable is only initialized by a call to `setScreenParent()` which almost certainly happens *after* you call `load()` on the `FXMLLoader` (typically you call load and then get a reference to the controller the loader created). Thus `populateBreedTable()` is called before `myController` is initialized, and is null. You can move the call to `populateBreedTable()` to `setScreenParent()` and it should work.